# The differential equation of the system of circles touching the y-axis at the origin is

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation of the system of circles touching the y-axis at the
origin is

(a) $x^2+y^2-2xy\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$

(b) $x^2+y^2+2xy\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$

(c) $x^2-y^2-2xy\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$

(d) $x^2-y^2+2xy\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$

The equation of the system of circles touching the y-axis at the origin is

$(x\pm r)^2+y^2=r^2$

$x^2+r^2\pm2xr+y^2=r^2$ .. (1)

$x^2\pm2xr+y^2=0$

Differentiating w.r.t x, $2x\pm2r+2y\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\mp r-x}{y}$

Putting this back in any of the above options, does not give (1) back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's put it back to (d): $$x^2-y^2+2xy\dfrac{dy}{dx} = x^2-y^2+2xy\dfrac{\mp r-x}{y}=x^2-y^2-2x^2\mp 2xr=-(x^2+y^2\pm2xr)=0$$ which is exactly the one below (1).

Comment: I need more patience .. Thanks for your help